# How can I remove the mutable variable in this mandelbrot function without recursion?

Tags: rust, immutability

The following function calculates the number of orbits it takes for an [mandelbrot fractal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelbrot_set) initial value to "escape":

```
extern crate num;

fn mandel_escape(x: f32, y: f32, limit: f32, orbits: u32) -> Option<u32> {
    let c = num::complex::Complex32::new(x, y);
    let mut z = c;
    for i in 0 .. orbits {
        z = z * z + c;
        if z.norm_sqr() > limit { return Some(i); }
    }
    None
}
```

I understand that there is no guaranteed tail call optimization in Rust. How might I be able to remove the mutable variable in this function without recursion?

Comment: Why? You could abuse some iterator adapters (`fold` and `take_while`, just ignoring the loop value), but that would just hide the mutability from you. This is perfectly idiomatic Rust. Is this a toy problem and you have some specific problem where something similar is making the borrow checker complain?

Comment: Also, trying to be helpful, not mean. Comments force terseness.

Comment: Would like to minimize mutability since it aids in understanding the logic. Referential integrity and all that.

Comment: Haha. Sorry. I meant referential transparency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible.

You need to create the values of `z` for each iteration at some point.  So either you have a mutable location to store each one in, or you need space for all of them.

You can hide the mutability inside an iterator, though:

```
struct MandelIterator {
    c: f32,
    z: f32,
}

fn mandel_iter(c: f32) -> MandelIterator {
    MandelIterator { c: c, z: 0.0 }
}

impl Iterator for MandelIterator {
    type Item = f32;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.z = self.z * self.z + self.c;
        Some(self.z)
    }
}

fn mandel_escape(x: f32, y: f32, limit: f32, orbits: usize) -> Option<usize> {
    for (i, z) in mandel_iter(x*y).enumerate().take(orbits) {
        if z.abs() > limit { return Some(i); }
    }
    None
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", mandel_escape(1.00001, 1.00001, 40999.0, 4));
}
```

Comment: Not exactly, I don't think.  You could write one, but the plain boring for loop is probably easier to understand.  :-)